# Como mostrar matriz triangulo superior derecho java

Tags: java

Hola buenas como muestro el tringulo superior de esta matriz gracias!!

```
System.out.println("Mostra la matriu");

        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(mat[i][j] + "\t");

            }
            System.out.println();

        }
```

Me gustaria el triangulo superior derecho osea la diagonal de la matriz para arriba.

Dada la matriz:

```
1234
5678
9012
3456
```

Me gustaria obtener la matriz:

```
1234
 678
  12
   6
```

Comment: por favor, agrega un ejemplo visual de lo que queres

Comment: matriz:6  4   4  6     quiero...     4  4  6 
          6  4   4  6                            4  6 
          6  4   4  6                                6

Comment: Perdon no te he etiquetado @gbianchi

Comment: no lo pongas en un comentario, por favor agregalo en la pregunta ordenado.

Comment: ya esta @gbianchi

Comment: A ver.. tu ejemplo, en el comentario, no es una matriz cuadrada. Yo se que parezco pesado, pero la idea es que la pregunta  sea clara. La matriz diagonal derecha para arriba es un concepto correcto. Ahora.. la matriz es cuadrada? o tiene dimensiones distintas? la solucion puede ser trivial para una cuadrada y mas compleja para una no cuadrada. Si no es molestia, podrias agregar en la pregunta un ejemplo de una matriz, aclarar si va a ser siempre cuadrada o no, y tambien un ejemplo del resultado que esperas? Gracias.

Comment: matriz cuadrada @gbianchi

Comment: Pero como dice @gbianchi, es una matriz simétrica o asimétrica?

Comment: simetrica @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer lo que quieres, debes pintar espacios en blanco en las posiciones de la matriz que estás descartando. Por lo que debes comprobar si la celda actual de la matriz la quieres pintar o descartar.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
            if (j < i) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();           
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Con esto deberia bastar:

```
System.out.println("Mostra la matriu");        
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(mat[i][j] + "\t");             
        }
        System.out.println();           
    }
```

Lo que hace es inicializar el segundo `for` en la posición horizontal igual a la vertical, lo que te va a ir generando el triangulo superior.

> Si quisieras generar el **triangulo inferior**, el `for` debería ser `for
>   (int j = 0; j < i;j++)`

Comment: Si pero quiero el lado superior derecho...no se como hacerlo...hahah

Comment: @IronMan entonces pone un ejemplo claro de que necesitas, porque esta respuesta es correcta.

Comment: @gbianchi lo siento ya lo he editado mejor..

Comment: Esta respuesta sigue siendo totalmente correcta